# Sending List<String> use javaMailSender

Tags: java, spring

```
@Service
public class SendingMailWhenDoOrder {

@Value("${img.imageMail.path}")
private String imagePath;

@Value("${spring.mail.username}")
private String emailFrom;

@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

public void sendingMessage(

        List<String> list) throws MessagingException {

    MimeMessage mimeMessage =  javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();

    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

    String toAddress = "mail@mail.com";

    helper.setTo(toAddress);

    String subject = "Oder on our Site is:";
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    for (String properties : list) {

        String[] split = properties.split("_");
        String name = split[0];
        Integer quantity = Integer.valueOf(split[1]);
        String photo = split[2];

        helper.setSentDate(new Date());

        helper.setText(name);

        FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File(imagePath));
        helper.addAttachment(photo, file);

    }
    helper.setFrom(emailFrom);

    javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
}
```

In List I recive somethink like that:

> - [qwertyuio_5_whisky/alfaSml.jpg, Tomintoul_3_whisky/Tomintoul.jpg, Alfa Suf_5_whisky/OldPulteney.jpg]

- I want sending in email the name products: qwertyuio, Tomintoul, Alfa
  Suf. But I recive only last product - Alfa Suf.

Comment: create and send within the `for` loop

Comment: I can send List<String>, but it's bad format for reading. I use all code in _**for**_ loop, only  helper.setFrom(emailFrom);

    javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage) without loop